# Re-defining the Python 3 print function in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, input, printing, built-in, redefine

I am trying to re-define the built-in print function in Python3 to have the flush keyword argument set to True by default. Something like the following (this does not actually work):

```
def print(message):
    print(message, flush=True)
```

*Alternatively, is there another way to set the flush keyword to True by default?*
Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Background info:

The reason why I want to do this is because it solves another problem I encountered.
I am running into a print function issue using Python3 in Jupyther Notebook.
When I use both print() and input(), the order of execution changes arbitrarily: sometimes the print output appears before the input prompt and sometimes the order is reversed. The following code produces two different outputs when run multiple times.

```
print("1")
x = input("2")
print("3")
```

Because my reputation score does not allow me to include images in this question, here are links to the two outcomes:
[Output version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YF89.png),
[Output version 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIe9Q.png).
This appears to be a known issue related to the print function's standard out buffering, and a solution is to use print() with the flush keyword argument set to True: `print("somestring",flush=True)`. This will run the print output immediately without buffering, preserving the intended order of the outputs.

Comment: A `partial` might help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: You can set it with `from functools import partial`, and then `print = partial(print, flush=True)`.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. and @Willem! That worked like a charm.
    from functools import partial
    print = partial(print,flush=True)
Using print after this modification produces the correct order of outputs in Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: P.S.: Sorry for the layout, still figuring out how to format code in a comment.

Comment: You have to use backticks! `\``

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that might work is using `python -u` or setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` in the environment before starting the script.

```
python -u <script name>
```

... or ...

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python <script name>
```

ref:  https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u